# Turning URLs into embeds - ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm currently migrating a Wordpress blog to Contentful. During that migration I want to transform urls, e.g. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psil6MKUXeE`, into embeds.

Let's say I got this text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psil6MKUXeE

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psil6MKUXeE

Dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
```

How can I extract multiple urls (in this case youtube) and replace them with the youtube embed code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to replace `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=video_id` with an iframe that holds your video.

You can do something like this:

```
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psil6MKUXeE'

value = url.match(/v=(.*)$/)[1]

target = "<iframe width='854' height='480' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/#{value}' frameborder='0' allow='autoplay; encrypted-media' allowfullscreen></iframe>"
```

This will generate the links in the embeded video format that you want, implementing a script is a bit hard with the information you've provided, but putting this inside a loop that contains files and the lines to be replaced should no be hard. If you're working on Linux, you could even do this with `sed` on the whole repository.

Answer (score 0):

```
TEXT = 'your text with links to youtube videos'

url_regex = /https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch\?v=(\w+)/

iframe_tag = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/\1?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>'

TEXT.gsub(url_regex, iframe_tag)
```

regex could be simplified to something like `/https.+?v=(\w+)/` if all links in text goes to youtube.

you should change `iframe_tag` params to fit your requirments on autoplay, sizes etc.